# How do I get the path to the most recent photo in the photos library? (As a NSUrl or string)

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I need to get the file path to the most recent image in the photo library. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to get only the most recent photo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AssetsLibrary to access the user's photos.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:group.numberOfAssets - 1] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result) {
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep;
                rep = [result defaultRepresentation];
                UIImage *image;
                image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

                //Now you can write this UIImage to a file path in your app's directory for future use

                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];
    }
    *stop = NO;
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to just access the most recent photos.